# How do I assign ranges of values of one of my columns to a set color in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am extremely new to R and coding in general, so please be patient with me! I have looked everywhere for the solution but everything I have tried hasn't worked or I haven't understood it, so I would appreciate any help you could give me.

I am trying to make a dot plot such that the colors correspond to a range of fold change values and the size of the dot corresponds to the p-value. I start by passing in a csv file with four columns Genes, Concentration, fold change, and p-value. Below is some sample data and the code I have been trying to generate a dot plot with concentration on the x-axis, genes on the y-axis and each dot color corresponding to fold change (but I want to specify a range of values corresponding to one color as below) and size of the dot is p-value.

```
    genes <- c('ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN', 'ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'JKL', 'LMN')
    concentration <- c('PR1.2', 'PR1.2','PR1.2', 'PR1.2','PR1.2', 'PR1.2','PR2.4', 'PR2.4','PR2.4', 'PR2.4','PR2.4', 'PR2.4')
    foldchange <- c(577.19, 2.642, -697.90, 50.23, 12.582, -30.542, -15.376, 30.674, -1.973, -5.324, -132.761, 146.678)
    pval <- c(4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3,1,1,4,4)
    data <- data.frame(genes, concentration, foldcahnge, pval)
   
    # now make dot plot using ggplot2 
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=concentration, y=genes, size=pval)) + labs(y="Gene") +
         geom_point(alpha = 0.9) + geom_point(aes(colour = cut(foldchange), c(Inf, 500, 250, 
                                             100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2, -2, 5, -10, -25, -50, 
                                             -100, -250, -500, -Inf)))) + 
         scale_color_manual(name = "fold change", values= c("(500, Inf]" = "firebrick4", 
                                                            "(250, 500]" = "firebrick", 
                                                            "(100, 250]" = "red3",
                                                            "(500, 100] = "red2", 
                                                            "(25, 50]" = "red",
                                                            "(10, 25]" = "firebrick2", 
                                                            "(5, 10]" = "firebrick1", 
                                                            "(2, 5]" = "rosybrown1", 
                                                            "(-2, 2]" = "gray98"
                                                            "(-5, -2]" = "lightskyblue",
                                                            "(-10, -5]" = "deepskyblue", 
                                                            "(-25, -10]" = "dodgerblue2", 
                                                            "(-50, -25]" = "dodgerblue4", 
                                                            "(-100, -50]" = "blue"
                                                            "(-250, -100]" = "blue3"
                                                            "(-500, -250]" = "darkblue"
                                                            "(-Inf, -500]" = "navy"),
                         labels = c("500", "250", "100", "50", "25", "10", "5", "2", "-2", "-5", "-10", "-25", "-50", "-100", "-250", "-500"))
    p + scale_size(range = c(1,4), breaks = c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("pval >0.05", "0.01<pval<0.05", "0.001<pval<0.01", "pval<0.001")
```

When I run it, it gives me a warning message: "Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_point). When I make the plot, 10 dots are filled with black, which I presume is the NA value. Also, the legend only goes from -25 to 100 when I run this code. I want these particular ranges to be able to extend the code to other datasets I am working with and to be able to compare across these data sets easily. Can anyone explain to me why I am getting the error message and why the legend only displays a subset of the data?

Thanks in advance for any help y'all can provide!

Comment: The issue is that except for the first category `"(500, Inf]"` there is no space after the comma in the default labels returned by `cut`, e.g. the second category is `"(250,500]"` instead of `"(250, 500]"`. Hence, these categories are removed. To solve this remove the spaces after the commas in `scale_color_manual(..., values = ...)`. Concerning the legend, ggplot2 by default drops unused factor levels. To prevent that try with `scale_color_manual(..., drop=FALSE)`